# Unknown language on back of paintings

Tags: cross-linguistic, written-language, russian

Can you clarify what language these writings are in and what they say?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Certainly that's Cyrillic, so it's likely Slavic. My guess is Russian.

Comment: It is Russian...

Comment: Could we possibly ban the use of "unknown language" to mean "a language which I personally am not able to read"? Russian is hardly an unknown language.

Answer (score 5):

The first one is called Поцелуев мост ([Potseluev Bridge](http://www.saint-petersburg.com/bridges/potseluev-bridge/) or literally `Bridge of Kisses`) and the second one Утро (Morning). The artist is Покидышев (Pokidyshev).

This [transliteration table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Russian#Transliteration_table) is useful when you need to translate Russian but aren't familiar with the Cyrillic alphabet. I use it with Google Translate.

Comment: @MattStanford: At Stack Exchange you don’t thank, you accept an answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

A little comment on above. "Поцелуев мост" does not mean 'Bridge of kisses'. It's just 'Potseluev's Bridge' (in Saint-Petersburg, Russia).